# Как взаимодействовать с инлайн кнопкой другим ботом?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, inline

хочу автоматизировать один процесс, в котором требуется взаимодействие с несколькими ботами в телеграмме, но у тех ботов с которыми я хочу взаимодействовать своим, инлайн кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ - никак. Для безопасности все обработчики в мессенджерах с API для ботов ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО сделаны через обратную связь. То бишь бот может только 'видеть' сообщения в чате и взаимодействовать с ними как обычный модератор (если бот модератор), ну и 'видеть', что делают с его сообщениями.

Comment: может ты не так понял, мне нужно просто автоматичеки купить прокси в боте, а в том боте кнопки инлайн

Comment: Я понял. И сказал, почему невозможно. Используй сервисы прокси (читай VPN) с API и автоматической покупкой через него.